# How can I prevent a jquery resizeable div to receive the resize click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, click

I create a div and then:

```
$("#div").resizable({
    disabled:true
});
```

Then I enable the resize behaviour and at the same time i want to handle a click on the div:

```
$("#div").on("click", myHandler);
$("#div").resizable( "option", "disabled", false);

function myHandler() {
    console.log("div clicked");
}
```

If now I drag the bottom-right corner of the div I can resize it, but when I release the drag if the mouse pointer is inside the div (this happens when shrinking it) `myHandler()` is also called. Since `myHandler()` is supposed to handle a different behavior - and not the resizing - how can I solve this?

What I've tried so far with no success:

```
$("#div").resizable({
    disabled:true,
    stop: function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about only doing the click handler when the mouse position is at the same place as it started?

```
var left = 0;
var top = 0; 

("#div").on({
        mousedown: function(e) {
            left  = e.pageX;
            top   = e.pageY;
        },
        mouseup: function(e) {
            if (left === e.pageX && top === e.pageY) {
                console.log('click');
            }
        }
});
```